# Самая минималистская IDE для C++

Tags: c++, ide

Ищу самую минималистскую IDE для C++ с вот такими требованиями:

1. Небольшой инсталятор под windows с уже включенным в него компилятором
2. UI состоит из редактора кода + опции: открыть/сохранить, компилировать/запустить
3. Без использования сторонних библиотек
4. Поддержка новых стандартов
5. Только для создания консольных программ
6. Отображение вывода ошибок

Comment: Без 4 - OpenWatcom. Но лично у меня минимализм - это очень настраиваемый редактор FTE + VC++ в командной строке, вызываемой из редактора (можно OW, можно GCC) с последующим отображением ошибок и переходом в нужную строку.. Если нужно - ну, работаю с Visual, но для простых вещей предпочитаю FTE. Жалко, что его не развивают... а более современного аналога найти не удается. Не удовлетворяет только первому пункту - компилятор надо ставить отдельно.

Comment: @Harry а у openwatcom какой последний стандарт?

Comment: @perfect, а отладчик вам разве не нужен??? Просто все выше описанное укладывается в Sublime хоть это и не IDE. ну и встроенный компилятор там только под линуксом)

Comment: @Alex.B мне вот такое надо http://cpp.sh/ , и что бы это просто устанавливалось (локально)

Comment: @perfect 2003 недоделанный :(

Comment: @perfect  такие онлайновые компиляторы - Wandbox и прочие - это не один пакет,  даже если не считать веб-сервер и сам java-модуль, реализующий эту страничку. В действительности там стоит компилятор и не один, под chroot, это сделано под линукс. Все приходится ставить настраивать отдельно, как всегда в мире программного обеспечения, за ширмой минимализма стоит огромный айсберг ПО и настроек, которые необходимо сделать.

Comment: @Swift то есть вы считаете что это все нельзя впихнуть в один инсталер?

Comment: @perfect Можно, флаг вам в руки. Как со всем открытым ПО, оно сделано руками тех, кому очень приспичило. Если говорить о простоте (и легкости ) установки, наверно ничего лучше Эклипс с mingw в комплекте нет. Может, есть виндовая версия NetBeans, икогда не видел.

Comment: @Swift netbeans под виндой визуально убог, лучше уж тогда саблайм с плагинами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую Вам [VS code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), во-первых он от Microsofta, во-вторых это простой текстовый редактор по типу sublime, встроенная удобная коллекция расширений и плагинов.
IDE-шка очень живая и перспективная (обновления раз в месяц).

Comment: сейчас посмотрим что это

Comment: теперь бы разобраться как к ней компилятор прицепить, похоже там все есть

Comment: спасибо помогло, там плагин wandbox-vscode есть , установка пару секунд.